# RAW Bayer demosaic directly to YUV without going through RGB

Tags: rgb, yuv, demosaicing

I'm looking to demosaic RAW bayer images straight to YUV format and time is crucial. Online algorithms I found go through RAW->RGB and then RGB->YUV. is there a direct way? A c++/python/Pseudo code would be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You can always do RGB -> YUV as a post processor.